# Make Shopware 6 Tabs Component <sw-tabs> work

Tags: shopware, shopware6

How do I get  Shopware 6 component to work properly? I am still learning

```
<sw-tabs>
    <sw-tabs-item>
        Content Name
    </sw-tabs-item>
    <sw-tabs-item>
        Content Age
    </sw-tabs-item>

<p>List of names</p>
<p>List of Ages </p>

</sw-tabs>
```

I want a situation when 'Content Name' is clicked, the paragraph for names displays, and when 'Content Age' is clicked, the paragraph for names shows instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read `<sw-tabs>` component in core to more detail ( `https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/trunk/src/Administration/Resources/app/administration/src/app/component/base/sw-tabs/index.js` ), or you can read the example code of the core component written (`https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/trunk/src/Administration/Resources/app/administration/src/module/sw-settings-search/component/sw-settings-search-searchable-content/sw-settings-search-searchable-content.html.twig`). But I will show you an example of your situation.

```
<sw-tabs
    position-identifier="content-name-age"
    :default-item="contentName"
>
    <template #default="{ active }">
    <sw-tabs-item
        :name="'contentName'"
        :title="name-tab"
        :active-tab="active"
    >
        Content Name
    </sw-tabs-item>

    <sw-tabs-item
        :name="'contentAge'"
        :title="age-tab"
        :active-tab="active"
    >
        Content Age
    </sw-tabs-item>
    </template>

    <template #content="{ active }">
    <div
        v-if="active === 'contentName'"
    >
        <p>List of names</p>
    </div>

    <div
        v-if="active === 'contentAge'"
    >
        <p>List of Ages </p>
    </div>
    </template>
</sw-tabs>
```

Comment: We don't have to do it the same way that it is done in core. We can even make our own tabs. E.g. This code is extremely convoluted and unintuitive, and so is the code in core. Personally I ended up doing it my own way, using ``sw-tabs``; **1:** each tab looks like this ``<sw-tab-item @click="activeItem(index) :active="activeItemId == index">``, allowing me to easily tell which tab is active directly in my `.twig` **2.:** ``activeItem`` simply assigns the index number of the tab to ``this.activeItemId`` – but it seriously needs better doc from official Shopware side. Also, I use `v-for`.